# swift4: how to check if user logged befor tab bar item clicked

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.1

This question has been asked before and has been answered, my question is not unique but there must be something missing. I'm simply trying to check if user logged in to app before as his data stored in `UserDefaults` but it doesn't work for me, this is the class of my `TabBarViewController`

```
class TabViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
}
// UITabBarDelegate
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("Selected item")
}

// UITabBarControllerDelegate
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if(viewController is MessagesViewController) {
        print("trueee")
        if(UserStorage.id == "") {
           Toast.toast(messsage: "not loggoed user", view: self.view)
        } 
    } else {
        print("faaaaaaaalse")
    }
    print("Selected view controller")
}
}
```

i want to check if user open `MessageViewController` then if user is logged in to print something but it always print `faaaaaaaalse`

> > > note: `Toast.toast()` is a function i created to show toast
> > >        and `UserStorage.id` returns user id stored in USerDefaults

this is image which shows my structure:
[image: this is image which shows my structure]
what should I do ?

Comment: can you show your storyboard? Cause I have copied you code and it works for me

Comment: @SergeyPolozov I'd added an image, can you check it!

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just your tab bar’s root controllers are 2 navigaton controllers, not MessageViewController. Firstly with tabBarController you have to find navigationController which contains your MessageViewController than in this navigation find the needed ViewController.

So I have the solution for you:

```
import UIKit

class TabbarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
    // for tab bar initialization
    if let viewControllers  = self.viewControllers,
        viewControllers.count >= 1,
        // the index of viewController is 0 here, but if your tab bar's started controller is not 0 you can set yours
        let navigationController = viewControllers[0] as? UINavigationController {
        for controller in navigationController.viewControllers {
            if let messagesViewController = controller as? MessagesViewController {
                doWithMessagesViewControllerWhatYouWant(_viewController: messagesViewController)
            }
        }
    }
}

// UITabBarControllerDelegate
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController{
        for controller in navigationController.viewControllers {
            if let messagesViewController = controller as? MessagesViewController {
                doWithMessagesViewControllerWhatYouWant(_viewController: messagesViewController)
            }
        }
    }
}

private func doWithMessagesViewControllerWhatYouWant(_viewController: MessagesViewController) {
    print("do some operations with messagesViewController")
    if(UserStorage.id == "") {
       Toast.toast(messsage: "not loggoed user", view: self.view)
    } 
}

}
```

Comment: thank you, is there any way to perform back button action from tab bar root view controller

Comment: @Al-shimaaAdel where ?